# ngFor creates unwanted copies of ng-template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an issue with ngFor directive, and I just can't find a way around it:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user.images.length > 0">
   <div *ngFor="let image of images">
        <img
           *ngIf="image.isProfileImage; else noImage"
           [src]="image.path"
        />
   </div>
</ng-container>
                    
<ng-template #noImage>
   <img src="https://someplaceholder.com"/>
</ng-template>
```

So, if the image is "profile image", use it. If not, use the template with the placeholder image. In some cases, if there are more images in the array and none of them is a profile image, it shows the `ng-template` but duplicated many times (by number of images in the array)..., but it should show it only once and "break out" of the loop.

Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: What would make it break out of the loop?

Comment: @Pointy I really don't know, I'm all new to angular, so I thought that there might be some in-template solution

Comment: The code works as expected; to do what you want to do you need to write code that does what you want. You can use `images.some(i => i.isProfileImage)` to find out whether to display the ngFor or noImage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to break out of an ngFor loop. However, there is a way to solve your problem.

You can create a method in your component that will loop over the array and check if there's a profile image there, then you can alter your HTML and you check wether the array contains a profile image or not. If not, then you can just show the ngTemplate.

**Example**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="user.images.length">
<ng-container *ngIf="containsProfileImage(); else noImage">
   <div *ngFor="let image of images">
        <img
           *ngIf="image.isProfileImage"
           [src]="image.path"
        />
   </div>
</ng-container>
</ng-container>
                    
<ng-template #noImage>
   <img src="https://someplaceholder.com"/>
</ng-template>
```

```js
containsProfileImage(): boolean{
   let returnVal = false;
   
   this.user.images.forEach(image => {
      if (image.isProfileImage) {
         returnVal = true;
         return;
      }
   }

   return returnVal;
}
```

EDIT: **Alternative solution**

As [Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g) said as a response. You can also filter your images by the images that have profile images. This way you can check whether there is atleast one image in the filtered array. If not, show the `noImage` ngTemplate.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="user.images.length">
<ng-container *ngIf="filteredImagesLength; else noImage">
   <div *ngFor="let image of images">
        <img
           *ngIf="image.isProfileImage"
           [src]="image.path"
        />
   </div>
</ng-container>
</ng-container>
                    
<ng-template #noImage>
   <img src="https://someplaceholder.com"/>
</ng-template>
```

```js
get filteredImagesLength(): number {
   return user.images.filter(i => i.isProfileImage)?.length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it's a lot clearer to me how to do these things now. The first solution has worked (needed to replace break with return however), the second solution threw some errors regarding having filter() etc inside the HTML, just FYI